# Access Odoo database from outside while Odoo deployed in AWS lightsail

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, odoo-12

I have installed AWS in a Linux VM at AWS Lightsail. Now need to access database using a DB client from my laptop. Somehow I am not able to connect the DB via port 5432.

I can access port 22 ftp after add a rule in AWS networking but not port 5432.
I tried to enable Linux VM firewall, but it did break all my connections.
Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

Did you change `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf` already?

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment on the OP's question

Comment: Well, if it turns out he didn't change `listen_addresses`, then it would become an answer :)